# Application hangs while waiting for WebBrowser control to complete

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, browser, webbrowser-control

Why does my application hang until WebBrowserDocumentCompleted completes loading the page? What can I do to keep my application responsive during this time?

> disabled subscription "`DocumentCompleted`"

The program also freezes during the method `wb.Navigate ("http:// ....");`

```
Can you post some code to show us what you have done?
```

Clicking a button and go to page

```
private void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.settingsForm.tEmail.Text == "" || this.settingsForm.tPassword.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Отсутствует логин и\\или пароль для входа на сервер МосВара.\nВвести их можно, нажав на кнопку \"Настройки\".", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        return;
    }
    wb.Navigate("http://www.moswar.ru");
}
```

**Event handler**

```
private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath) return;
    if (wb.Document.GetElementById("login-email") != null)
    {
        wb.Document.GetElementById("login-email").InnerText = settingsForm.tEmail.Text;
        wb.Document.GetElementById("login-password").InnerText = settingsForm.tPassword.Text;
        GetElementsByClassName(new string[] {"button luxury"})[0].InvokeMember("click");
    }

    if (e.Url.AbsoluteUri == "http://www.moswar.ru/player/" || e.Url.AbsoluteUri == "http://www.moswar.ru/player/#login")
    {
        wb.Navigate("http://www.moswar.ru/metro/");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code to show us what you have done?

Comment: Try to set the Proxy to Null

Comment: well still browser run on it own thread, pls post the code sir

Answer (score 2):

You can only interact with a window if it responds to windows messages, and you can only respond to windows messages if your UI thread is processing them. So if you ask your UI thread to load the web page, it will block (become unresponsive) until the web request completes.

Your options are:

- Speed up the web request. Perhaps proxy settings are making it take a long time or time out. (Or possibly it's just taking a long time for the server response to get back to you in which case you probably can't do much to speed things up).
- If you can't make it faster, then you need to do it in the background. Use a web request API (if available) that is asynchronous, or call the web request from a worker thread yourself, so that your UI thread can continue responding to user inputs until the web data is available. This is quite complex stuff to learn if you don't know it yet though, so be prepared to put in some time and effort on it.

Comment: Can be little example with my version of

Comment: I don't know enough about WebBrowser to give you specifics. It looks as though Navigate is asynchronous, in which case it may not be the thing that is blocking your program. Or perhaps your code is doing other things (changing other WebBrowser settings or reacting to WebBrowser events) that cause it to stall. Try to create a test program that does as little as possible to see if you can get it to work, and (if it does) build up from there.

Comment: Navigate is async and will not block the UI thread. You can try the following: Start the app in debugging mode from within Visual Studio. When the app is blocked, quickly pause (break into the debugger). Then examine where the main UI thread is waiting. If necessary dig into parts of the stack that don't have source code available. Then report back.